# Use IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation in ASP.Net web api to talk to IDS4

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, identityserver4, identityserver3

We have setup Identity server 4 with .Net Core 2.1. We have ASP.Net Web API on .Net 4.6. This cannot be migrated to Core. I have installed IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation in this API project together with OWN and other neeeded packages. I can use a client and get the access token from the IdentityServer. When the client uses that token with the API, I get 401. I have searched the web for solutions but cannot find anything that I can use to make this work.
I tried this - https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation/issues/164
but did not work. I cannot find any samples. 
So my question is is it not possible to use IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation to talk to IDS4?

Do I need to setup IDS3 instead?

**UPDATE**

I turned on verbose logging and got the following

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:44333/connect/introspect application/x-www-form-urlencoded 70
IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware:Information: Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.IntrospectionEndpoint for /connect/introspect
IdentityServer4.Validation.ApiSecretValidator:Error: API validation failed.
IdentityServer4.Endpoints.IntrospectionEndpoint:Error: API unauthorized to call introspection endpoint. aborting.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 26.5186ms 401 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel:Information: Connection id "0HLIJ2C0UKBLN", Request id "0HLIJ2C0UKBLN:00000008": the application completed without reading the entire request body.
```

Below is my API code in Configuration method

```
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "https://localhost:44333",
            RequiredScopes = new[] { "api" },

            ClientId = "api",
            ClientSecret = "secret",

            //DelayLoadMetadata = true
        });

        app.UseWebApi(config);
```

Code on IDS4 side for the ApiResource.

```
    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new ApiResource("api", "MyApi") { ApiSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) } }
        };
    }
```

**UPDATE 2**

Yes I have enabled Trace. After bit more of playing around with the code and reinstalling the packages, I now get a different error.Request is made to /connect/accesstokenvalidation. This endpoint is not available in IDS4

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:44333/connect/accesstokenvalidation application/x-www-form-urlencoded 70
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 3.405ms 404 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel:Information: Connection id "0HLIJ9RBG591K", Request id "0HLIJ9RBG591K:0000000A": the application completed without reading the entire request body.

Comment: There is no reason why it won't work. IDS3 or 4 both using the same protocol. You must have something configured wrong. To debug, create a console client app and use that to access IDS4.

Comment: Have you got any samples?
I am able to get the access code from IDS4 using a client. However, when the client talks to the API using the token, it does not work. I did try to create ASP.Net Web API Core which worked with IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.
However in my case I cannot have ASP.NET Core for the API prject

Comment: Normally what I do, I would turn on verbose debug log in IDS4, you will likely find a clue in the log.

Comment: Please see update for the logs and code snippet

Comment: If I remove DelayLoadMetadata = true, I get the following error

System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt.IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider' from assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.'

Comment: Your log does not seem verbose enough... , are you sure you turned on `debug`? use the `trace` option if you have too... http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/logging.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184245/discussion-between-amitesh-and-rosdi-kasim).

Comment: Please see update 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Finally I managed to solve it after 3 days of headache.

connect/accesstokenvalidation was because of old version of IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation. I updated this to version 2.15.1 and also downgarded 
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt to 4.0.2.206221351

I also added scopes to ApiResource as below. However this might not be required. I have not tested without it yet.

```
    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new ApiResource("my_api", "SmartBiz Api")
            {
                ApiSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },
                Scopes =
                {
                    new Scope("the_api")
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Thanks for your help Rosdi Kasim

Answer (score 0):

I spent a few days fighting an issue, so i figured i'd add an answer with my findings. I'm using IDS4 and .net 4.7 web api.

The major pain point when validating a client "API" that is a .net 4.7 app, authenticating with an IdentityServer4 dotnet core token server. the issue is this.

The ClientID and the ClientSecret set in the Startup.cs of the .net 4.7 Web API Project are the ID and Secret of the API Resource.

First, you hit the IDS4 /token endpoint to get a token. The request requires the client_id and client_secret (and other required values) set in the Config.cs file of the IDS4 project.

```
  public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> Apis =>
        new ApiResource[]
        {
            new ApiResource("api", "My DotNet 4.7 API"){ //.net 4.7 API clientId
                ApiSecrets = new List<Secret>()
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())      //.net 4.7 API client secret
                },
                Scopes = { "api"}
            }
        };

       public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
        new Client[]
        {
           new Client
            {
                ClientId = "client",

              ...

                // secret for authentication
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret1".Sha256())
                },

              ...
            }
        };
```

now with that token, you pass it to the the .net 4.7 Api Endpoint. This is where i was getting "401 UnAuthorized". The solution was in the "Startup" file, specifically this part:

```
       app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(
            new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
            {
                .....
                
                //this is the API Resource Id and Secret for that API resource
                ClientSecret = "secret",
                ClientId = "api"
            });
```

For some reason that was not clear to me that I had to use the API Resource Values in the config of the API. Which makes sense now. But for some reason, none of the resources I ready specifically called this out.